# Low jitter audio on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to load a small audio clip like a beep into memory, and schedule playback after x seconds with very low jitter. My application ideally gets less than +-1ms, but +-5ms could still be useful. The time is synchronized to a remote application without a microphone. My question is what kind of jitter can I expect from the audio APIs, and are they all equal in this regard?

I'm not familiar with the audio APIs, but from the latency discussions I've seen the number 5.8ms using remoteIO audio units. Does this mean +-3ms would be the best precision possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set this process as Real-Time to have a guarantee of low delay, otherwise you can get jitter in seconds because operating system can decide to make some background job.
Once you got it as real-time, you might archive lower delay.
Please check with Apple if you can make process real-time (with scheduling options). You might want to have extra permissions and kernel level support in your app to do it properly, that you can have guaranteed 1ms delay for audio app.